# Annoymous Sharepoint REST Proxy

Tags: jquery, rest

I am trying to create a local proxy which calls a sharepoint rest query.

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string getJson()
        {


            string listRSSFeedUrl = "http://myurl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList";
            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(listRSSFeedUrl);
            req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            req.PreAuthenticate = true;
            var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            var feed = new XmlDocument();
            var feedStream = res.GetResponseStream();


            feed.Load(feedStream);

            return feed.InnerXml;

        }
```

How do I return the json format that the original rest query should return?

The jquery calling the method looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SharepointJson.aspx/getJson",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "Announcements:<br /><br />";


                $.each(data.d.results, function (i, result) {
                    //Display some properties 
                    markup += 'Title: ' + result.feed + '<br />';
                });
                //Call the jQuery append method to display the HTML 
                $('#displayDiv').append($(markup));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but you can try using JavaScriptSerializer:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
   {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var obj = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());
   }
}
```

and return deserialized object.